# Extended EditText has different styling applied to it?

Tags: android

I have a class that extends EditText. It does not do anything related to styling or drawing. On my device running android 4.4.4, the extended EditText has different styling than other EditText instances in my app. Why is that, and how can I have it just use the same styling that normal EditText instances use?

My extended EditText:

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {
    public MyEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
}
```

Usage in my layout:

```
<LinearLayout ... >
    <!-- this one is styled as expected. -->
    <EditText />

    <!-- my custom one is styled differently somehow. -->
    <com.test.me.MyEditText />
</LinearLayout>
```

The normal EditText has a blue underline for the focused state, while my custom one has a black underline.

Thanks

---- Update ----------

It seems the styling works fine on Lollipop, but every os version I've tried prior to Lollipop has this problem. I must be doing something wrong since extending an EditText is a really common thing to have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong constructor in your extended EditText. All constructors should be MyEditText() and not EditTextDelete().